# Display pro-blem with my graphics card

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

Since I made some updates to the drivers for my graphics card (I don't remember which update{s}), I have some display problems.  I cannot play any games, because after a few minutes I get this weird display: [image: My graphic card display].
Here is my graphics card description:

- Operating System:    Windows 7
- Professional, 32-bit DirectX version: 11.0
- GPU:     GeForce 7900 GS Driver
- version:     260.99 Core clock:      450 MHz
- Memory clock:        660 MHz (1320 MHz data rate)
- Memory interface:    256-bit
- Total available graphics memory: 1535 MB
- Dedicated video memory:  256 MB
- GDDR3 System video memory:   0 MB
- Shared system memory:    1279 MB
- Video    BIOS version:   5.71.22.42.07
- IRQ:         16
- Bus:         PCI Express x16

Can somebody tell me what the problem is so I can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using Windows System Restore to go back to before you did the update and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: What's the problem?  Is it because it's not in full screen mode (e.g., does it switch out from "full screen" mode to "windowed" mode?)?  If so, try pressing Alt-Enter as this works in most of these types of applications to alternate between windowed and full screen modes.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Even if I am in fullscreen mode, I still have the same problem. I use this screen resolution because I wanted to take the image snapshot.

Comment: I would start by trying some older drivers if you had it working properly in the past.... since you don't remember when you updated them this may be difficult but I would start with the one before the latest and work your way back until you find the one that worked.

Comment: @Dimitri:  Okay, so the problem isn't related to switching between windowed and full screen mode.  What is the problem?

Comment: Ok, I don't know how to explain my problem but I will do my best. I have a display problem with my graphic card. When I play games, I have weird display similar to this one : http://hwzone.co.il/reviews-files/pc_problems_guide/artifacts.jpg. Sometimes, this problem happens to my dekstop also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you don't know what Driver's you have installed, you may have installed drivers through Windows Update and that could've caused the problem perhaps.

You can try removing the Nvidia Drivers completely and then install the latest ones from the website.

http://www.nvidia.com/object/win7-winvista-32bit-266.58-whql-driver.html

I would also use Driver Sweeper to get rid of all traces of Nvidia Drivers so you know you're installing a complete fresh package with no conflicts.

http://downloads.guru3d.com/Guru3D---Driver-Sweeper-(Setup)_d1655.html